# Элемент меняет расположение при изменении разрешения

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы анимированный колокольчик отображался корректно при любом разрешении экрана, а то выходит так как на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS:

```
}
.logo .bell {
  width: 6%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14.5%;
  top: 26%;

}
.logo .bell:hover, .logo .bell:focus {
    animation: bellshake .5s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-origin: top right;
 }


@keyframes bellshake {
  0% { transform: rotate(0); }
  15% { transform: rotate(5deg); }
  30% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }
  45% { transform: rotate(4deg); }
  60% { transform: rotate(-4deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(2deg); }
  85% { transform: rotate(-2deg); }
  92% { transform: rotate(1deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0); }
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш html и более полный css

Comment: укажите размеры в px а уже для мелких разрешений уже scale zoom итд

Comment: Я бы ещё не использовал абсолютную позицию. Только относительную для таких вещей

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте родительскому контейнеру position: relative.

Если родитель .logo:

```
.logo {
position: relative;
}
```

Для полноты картины добавьте html код

Answer (score 0):

При абсолютном позиционировании нужно указать точки отсчета в пикселях, чтобы колокольчик не съезжал при разных разрешениях.